# Keycloak remove first and last name from registration form

Tags: validation, registration, keycloak

I would like to register users only using email and password.

Removing fields from register.ftl, will remove them from the UI, but the server will still validate them.

This question is very similar:
[Keycloak Remove First Name and Last Name fields on Registration Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776626/keycloak-remove-first-name-and-last-name-fields-on-registration-screen)

Problem is I could not find these validation check in the newer version of Keycloak, I am using v 4.8.1.

Best solution would be to remove them entirely and keep validation for the other fields, but disabling the form validation and using custom one also works for me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did as workaround for keycloak v4.8.3.

There is no option to disable form registration form validation anymore, so you have two options

- disable keycloak registration flow entirely and rely only on social
  login (this is actually a very popular approach in general not just
  with keycloak)
- Got to keycloak-4.8.1.Final/themes/base/login, find register.ftl and add default value to first and last name, then add style display none to them so they won't show. Like so:

  ```
   <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} ${messagesPerField.printIfExists('firstName',properties.kcFormGroupErrorClass!)}" style="display:none">
          <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
              <label for="firstName" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">${msg("firstName")}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
              <input type="text" id="firstName" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" name="firstName" value="temp_first_name"/>
          </div>
   </div>
  ```

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response, how could one disable the keycloak registration flow entirely?

Comment: Not sure if you can. But you can just ignore it an use KC as a service. However if you want to use the social login part as well it becomes a little bit more complicated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219092/keycloak-social-login-rest-api

Comment: Thanks, we ended up using a hard coded value for the email adres as a mapping, this way the registration form doesn't shop up anymore